# accessing host ip and port in play framework scala template?

Tags: scala, playframework

How to access the server host ip and port in playframework template?

**Background**

Let say I start play using the command on a server with ip: `192.168.1.10`:

```
./activator "run 12345"
```

How to make the `app/views/index.scala.html` when I visit 192.168.1.10/index.html (assumed I have setup the appropriate route)?

```
<html>
    <body>
        192.168.1.10:12345
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what is it you're trying to do?  Are you trying to connect to the server that you've started on port 12345 of 192.168.1.10?

Comment: Thanks.
It turns out that I can create that page with the ip/port seen by the client using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest solution for you is using the HTTP request. Check out play.api.mvc.Http

```
   /**
     * The HTTP host (domain, optionally port)
     */
    lazy val host: String = headers.get(HeaderNames.HOST).getOrElse("")
```

In Play! you can get access to the HTTP request by using the Action builder that accepts the function (Request) => Result

```
  def getHostPort = Action { request =>
    Ok(s"This page served from ${request.host}")
  }
```

If your server is listening for HTTP on 192.168.1.10:12345 hitting that endpoint will render the string *"This page served from  192.168.1.10:12345"*

But you can easily modify it to pass request.host to your template